# Separar variáveis de string json

Tags: php, json, string

Tenho a seguinte string:

```
string(292) "
{"access_token":"ab5f49438xfbc2df2a6a927a02b5c2e2442am982c71ee8re4aee1b2c64783ddc7cab4050ed05d6aa",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":300,
"refresh_token":"ab4156db100f148b6cgd7e17097e1f1c25dcf32a53ec64w287c0bcc5b8f8aa2d0799a413567b8d73",
"scope":"user_account send_currency currency_exchange"
}"
```

Como eu poderia separar em variáveis esta string e mostrar o valor de cada ?
`echo $access_token` ? ou `echo $token_type` ?

Comment: Já tentou usar `json_encode($texto);`?

Comment: Sim, por enquanto não esta dando certo

Answer (score 1):

Olá. Primeiro de tudo será utilizar o json_decode, após isso você tem um objeto com as propriedades desejadas. Uma vez com elas em mãos, você pode acessar via objecto ou externar as variáveis como solicitado. Segue exemplo:

```
<?php

$json_string = '{
    "access_token": "ab5f49438xfbc2df2a6a927a02b5c2e2442am982c71ee8re4aee1b2c64783ddc7cab4050ed05d6aa",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_token": "ab4156db100f148b6cgd7e17097e1f1c25dcf32a53ec64w287c0bcc5b8f8aa2d0799a413567b8d73",
    "scope": "user_account send_currency currency_exchange"
}';

$json_parse = json_decode($json_string);

echo "<pre>";
echo "access_token  :" . $json_parse->access_token  . PHP_EOL;
echo "token_type    :" . $json_parse->token_type    . PHP_EOL;
echo "expires_in    :" . $json_parse->expires_in    . PHP_EOL;
echo "refresh_token :" . $json_parse->refresh_token . PHP_EOL;
echo "scope         :" . $json_parse->scope         . PHP_EOL;
echo "</pre>";

// Transforma o escopo das variáveis acessíveis externamente
// O item deve ser um array, como o json_decode transforma em objeto
// precisamos transformar em array
extract((array) $json_parse);

echo "<pre>";
echo "access_token  :" . $access_token  . PHP_EOL;
echo "token_type    :" . $token_type    . PHP_EOL;
echo "expires_in    :" . $expires_in    . PHP_EOL;
echo "refresh_token :" . $refresh_token . PHP_EOL;
echo "scope         :" . $scope         . PHP_EOL;
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Resultado:

```
access_token  :ab5f49438xfbc2df2a6a927a02b5c2e2442am982c71ee8re4aee1b2c64783ddc7cab4050ed05d6aa
token_type    :Bearer
expires_in    :300
refresh_token :ab4156db100f148b6cgd7e17097e1f1c25dcf32a53ec64w287c0bcc5b8f8aa2d0799a413567b8d73
scope         :user_account send_currency currency_exchange

access_token  :ab5f49438xfbc2df2a6a927a02b5c2e2442am982c71ee8re4aee1b2c64783ddc7cab4050ed05d6aa
token_type    :Bearer
expires_in    :300
refresh_token :ab4156db100f148b6cgd7e17097e1f1c25dcf32a53ec64w287c0bcc5b8f8aa2d0799a413567b8d73
scope         :user_account send_currency currency_exchange
```

Pode visualizar a execução deste código [neste link](https://ideone.com/p1qfR3).

Comment: ótimo, ficou claro

Mas está sendo gerado assim nesse link:
http://www.agbsites.com/teste.php

com string(323), como ficaria ?

Comment: Acredito que esteja utilizando o var_dump para dar saída nesse texto, coloque apenas echo. Se possível, coloque o código que está gerando essa saída para ficar mais fácil lhe ajudar.

Comment: www.agbsites.com/gerar.txt

Coloquei nesse link Bruno, esta sendo gerado a partir desse código (API Json), ele gera a string e depois preciso pegar os dados em separados.

Comment: Consegui Bruno, so alterei var_dump para echo na saida e integrei com a  variavel de saída $response,

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json_parse = json_decode($response);
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Se tens uma string tens de converter em JSON e depois aceder à propriedade que queres.

Para:

- converter em json: usa o `json_decode`
- aceder a uma propriedade: `$json -> token_type`

Exemplo:

```
$string = '{
    "access_token":"ab5f49438xfbc2df2a6a927a02b5c2e2442am982c71ee8re4aee1b2c64783ddc7cab4050ed05d6aa",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "expires_in":300,
    "refresh_token":"ab4156db100f148b6cgd7e17097e1f1c25dcf32a53ec64w287c0bcc5b8f8aa2d0799a413567b8d73",
    "scope":"user_account send_currency currency_exchange"
}';
$json = json_decode($string);
echo $json -> token_type;
```

**Exemplo online: https://ideone.com/i4eil5**

Comment: Olá Sergio, obrigado

Mas no caso está sendo gerado assim como está no link abaixo:
http://www.agbsites.com/teste.php

com a string(323) como ficaria ?

Comment: @WellingtonAlves qual é o PHP que gera essa string?

Comment: Nesse link Sergio, é de uma API
www.agbsites.com/gerar.txt

Daí preciso separar as variáveis geradas

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, consegui resolver

Comment: @WellingtonAlves estava fora. Pois, em vêz de `var_dump($response);` devias ter somente `echo $response;` ou diretamente `$json = json_decode($response);` e depois como indiquei na resposta.